# SQL Query issue with joining get data that doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have date range: Date 1 and Date 2

in one table I have Date that are registered according to user logging in.

when I do SQL between Date1 to Date2, it only gives Date that exist.

so for example, 01-01-2016 to 01-04-2016: four days

I need:

```
01-01-2016 - 0
01-02-2016 - 5
01-03-2016 - 3
01-04-2016 - 0
```

instead I get:

```
01-02-2016 - 5
01-03-2016 - 3
```

because other two dates do not exist in the table.

how can I solve it?

I need to display all date selected with 0

Comment: If the data is not present then how it could return those data? Add them manually with code or in query.

Comment: Do you have a time table containing all dates?

Comment: MySQL is really bad at inventing non existant data. _Bad MySQL_ What we need is _MAGIC MYSQL_

Comment: @sagi NO I don't have timetable of calendar.

Comment: @sagi that makes it too heavy? I mean creating extra table with data every time

Comment: No, not every time, make it once for all date since lets say the year of 2000 and the year of 2030. then you will only have to join to it

Comment: @sagi hope you are not joking?

Comment: Not at all, calender table can be used in a lot of  different ways. You can easily find a script to create one on google.

Comment: Use something like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range to generate a date range, then left join each date to your data, replacing any nulls as required.

Comment: show your table structure (i mean create table code) @user4499992

Comment: You need to get your DeLorean up to 88 MPH. Then you'll be able to fix the issue.

Comment: @Dave watching too much Back to the future? I think you might be wright\